# Number of ways of selecting $k$-element subsets from an $n$-element set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-probability

I want to find the number of ways of selecting $k$-element subsets from an $n$-element set.

---

Suppose we select the elements one by one. There are $n$ ways of selecting the first one, leaving $n-1$ ways for the second, and so on, until we reach $n-k+1$ ways to select the $k$-th one, so there are:

$$n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)$$

ways. However, apparently we should divide by $k!$ Why? For what it's worth, I understand that we could select them two by two etc as well. I just don't understand how dividing by $k!$ fixes it all.

Comment: You are counting ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, and CBA as distinct.  That's okay, if the order in which the items are chosen matters, but if we only care *which* $k$ items are chosen, we have to divide by $k!$.

Comment: @saulspatz I've never done any combinatorics before now, so please forgive my dimwittedness, but where does this occur?

Comment: No apology needed.  Let's say you want to know the number of ways of selecting $3$ items from $10$.  You say the number of ways is $10\cdot9\cdot8$  What I'm saying is that you count the case where A,B,and C are selected $6$ times; once when they're selected in the order A,B,C; once when they're selected in the order A,C,B, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing by $k!$ is needed because in your

$$n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1),$$

you're actually permuting those $k$ element in a row. E.g. If you choose out

$$1,2,3$$

you will also count

$$1,3,2\\
2,1,3\\
2,3,1\\
3,1,2\\
3,2,1$$

since by your formula it just says $3\times2\times1=6,$ which includes all above shown, but they all represent the same set $\{1,2,3\}.$

Answer (score 1):

> Number of ways of selecting  $k$ element subsets from an  $n$ element set
>   $$=\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)! \times k!}$$

$$=\frac{n \times (n-1) ...\times (n-k+1)\times(n-k)!}{(n-k)! \times k!}$$

$$=\frac{n \times (n-1) ...\times (n-k+1)}{ k!}$$

Further if you want to know why we are dividing it by $k!$ without knowing the proof,it is as follows.You have $n$ ways to select the first ,$n-1$ ways for second and ....(n-k+1) for the last one .but as you are multiplying it,all the cases (permutation) will be covered,to avoid from duplication we divide it by $k!$

Comment: I'm confused. My question is where does the $k!$ come from right at the beginning?

Comment: i proved you why you need to divide by $k!$ .you are selecting $k$ sets from n element sets which is nothing but  n C k or $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: see the edited answer